# Как правильно задать условие при котором бы работал слайдер?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне необходимо, чтобы работал слайдер при экранах в 320px и 768px. при 320 я реализовал как мне надо, а вот при 768 получается что слайдеры прокручиваются до пустого места и потом происходит зацикливание. короче условие для экрана 768 не работает. кто может подсказать почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  if (window.innerWidth = 320) {
    document.querySelector('.slider__next').addEventListener('click', function() {
        offset = offset + 304;
        if (offset > 912) {
            offset = 0;
        }
        sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
    });
    document.querySelector('.slider__prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
        offset = offset - 304;
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = 912;
        }
        sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
    });
} else {
    document.querySelector('.slider__next').addEventListener('click', function() {
        offset = offset + 593;
        if (offset > 608) {
            offset = 0;
        }
        sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
    });
    document.querySelector('.slider__prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
        offset = offset - 593;
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = 608;
        }
        sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
    });
}
```

Comment: Почему не решать эту проблему с помощью css задавая элементам размер в относительных величинах?

Comment: в смысле? можно по подробнее объяснить, пожалуйста?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/

Comment: это круто конечно, но все же хочется разобраться именно с js. что не так в условии что срабатывает только один участок кода для разных экранов. а не каждый для своего экрана

Comment: Потому что у вас присваивание в условии `window.innerWidth = 320`

Comment: == такое тоже не помогает. теперь получается работает код для экрана 768 пикселей и этот же код работает для 320 пикселей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё потому, что вы не понимаете как работают события.

```
const isMobile = () => window.innerWidth <= 320;

document.querySelector('.slider__next').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (isMobile()) {
        offset = offset + 304;
        if (offset > 912) offset = 0;
    } else {
        offset = offset + 593;
        if (offset > 608) offset = 0;
    }
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});
document.querySelector('.slider__prev').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (isMobile()) {
        offset = offset - 304;
        if (offset < 0) offset = 912;
    } else {
        offset = offset - 593;
        if (offset < 0) offset = 608;
    }
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});
```

Comment: то есть вы добавили константную переменную и присвоили ей.. , а дальше объясните пожалуйста или где прочитать можно про это? а так  работает как мне нужно спасибо.

Comment: Присвоил ей [стрелочную функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) которая возврщает `window.innerWidth <= 320` при какждом клике.

Comment: а как тогда получается что при 768 пикселях работает так как надо?

Comment: Пссмотрите внимательно на `if (isMobile()) {`